# Facebook Graph API - Is there a user id? we want to see how many times a user looked at each of our pages?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've looked through the Facebook Graph API docs but I haven't been able to find a user id (I found [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) referring to users, but it's actually referring to the user that manages the app).

We have several pages, lets say 40, and we want to see how many times a Facebook user has looked across our pages, is there a way to find a user id?

Comment: No, of course that is not possible, because that would be a severe privacy intrusion. You don't get any data about which _individual_ users are looking at your page.

Comment: @CBroe how is a user id a privacy issue? I don't need their name, address etc, just an id. I ask because I'm trying to further understand

Comment: That ID could be used to relate to the rest of the mentioned data again. // You have to keep in mind, that requesting this data on a large scale via API, is different from when the page admin looks at this via the UI. Plus there is a 3rd party involved here - the app developer. That might be you yourself in this specific situation, but usually it isn't. So it could be any shady person in some country far away, that would be able to gather this data en masse, simply because you and some other people are using their app on your pages.

Comment: @CBroe ahh I see, thank you for clarifying!